# Can't read Registry value with C#

Tags: c#, registry

I'm having a bit trouble. I'm doing a Programming-Project from school and I need to read all of the system info from the Registry using C#.
Now I'm using Microsoft.Win32 to access the Register, but I don't know where I can find all of the needed info (I've found CPU, GPU, MB and BIOS, but where can I find more usefull data? Like connected drives or amount of RAM and etc..)

Also, I can't present the GPU name for some reason. Here is the code (I'm using WinForm):

```
string gpu = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinSAT", "PrimaryAdapterString", null);
txtGPU.Text = "Your GPU is: " + gpu;
```

But for some reason it does not present (I see only the text "Your GPU is", but without the name of the GPU. I used the same trick to show the CPU name and it worked).

And one last thing, inside the *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor* there are folders as the amount of logical cores. How can I count the folders to present the amount of the logical cores?

Thanks for all helpers! Sorry for being a newbie..

Comment: Is _reading from registry_ a requirement? Because you know, there are the [Windows Management Instrumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page) classes

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time and the nice willing to answer. It is a requirement indeed. It seems like [Windows Management Instrumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page) Doesn't read anything from registry, but thanks anyway!

Do you happen to know something about the 2 other questions?

Comment: [Win32_Processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processor), [Win32_BaseBoard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-baseboard), [Win32_VideoController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-videocontroller) etc. Get this: [WMI Code Creator - Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) and/or this [Download WMI Code Generator](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/wmigen.php) to begin exploring.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me, I really appreciate that! Does WMI interacts at all with the Registry?

Comment: WMI *interacts* with everything. How does it matter where that information comes from or is stored in?

Comment: It matters since the requirement is to be able to read the Registry only and provide info about the PC on the screen

Comment: Then you cannot use WMI or direct API calls (as everyone else does :) Scrapping the Registry to gather this information is not exactly *standard procedure*. So, open up `msinfo32.exe`, look what it shows, search the Registry using the same strings and see what you can gather up like this.

Comment: BTW, you can get the names of the sub-keys with `var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor", false); var subKeys = key.GetSubKeyNames();` and iterate that collection to read the sub-keys by name (`"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", ...`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.
You have null because in default VS reading 32x registry.
You need set to 64x.

```
string subkey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinSAT";
    
RegistryKey localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
string value = localKey.OpenSubKey(subkey).GetValue("PrimaryAdapterString").ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked indeed. May I ask why when I run this code `string cpu = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0", "ProcessorNameString", null);` it reads the value without setting it to 64x?

Comment: Probably this entry is available in 32x registry. GPU only in 64x.
I haven't found any good explanation about this. I know this from my own experience in read registry in C#.